# excel - how to separate comma values into separate cells using a formula only

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, split

Data Source in Cell

```
A1 192.168.1.2,123.12.123.12,192.168.123.1,123.12.1.1,123.1.1.1
```

Separate this string by it's comma into each cell

1. using a formula
2. Not Using VBA

how do you separate this string by its comma in to each cell? Not using VB Script.

ex.

```
192.168.1.2,123.12.123.12,192.168.123.1,123.12.1.1,123.1.1.1
192.168.1.2,123.12.123.12
192.168.1.2
```

Results

```
B             C               D               E            F
192.168.1.2   123.12.123.12   192.168.123.1   123.12.1.1   123.1.1.1
192.168.1.2   123.12.123.12
192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) and see what `FILTERXML()` can do for you. For example, if one has Excel365, in `B1` use `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A2 =  any of these

```
192.168.1.2,123.12.123.12,192.168.123.1,123.12.1.1,123.1.1.1
192.168.1.2,123.12.123.12
192.168.1.2
```

This is the comma enumeration cells. Handles all any variation of commas 1-5. Add more as needed.

```
c1 =1 
D1 =2
E1 =3
F1 =4
G1 =5
```

B2 = (copy across the cells below the corresponding column enumeration cells.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,",",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),(C$1-1)*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
```